# Is there easy way to convert currency with php?

Tags: php, currency, euro

I was thinking is there any easy solution to convert euro prices to dollars with PHP. Something similar to date and time function maybe.

edit.
I have euro prices on the site but I'd like to have dollar prices along them too. So I need solution to auto calc dollars in real time.

Comment: Please post an example of your current currency string.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: Convert the formatting or the actual price?

Comment: @Fred-ii- This doesnt convert the price right?

Comment: @Loko whole bunch of examples in there they can start with. Question's unclear anyway. There were asked to post an example. If that guy wants to wait, great. I'm not. You know how things roll around here sometimes ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Agreed. Unclear question.

Comment: @Loko they could also replace whatever currency string they have with `$` or if they're wanting to convert integers here; who knows. Again; unclear question. Nowt they have an answer below, they can see that.

Comment: @IzirAtig Your edit: *"So I need solution to auto calc dollars in real time."* - what does this have to do with everything? This question is starting to look more like "too broad" at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a 3-rd party api to do this conversion for you. Please take a look at this one, for example: http://fixer.io/ .
Not to reinvent the wheel, I recommend you using a ready-made wrapper for actually making the requests. I've found this one which looks pretty thin and solid: https://github.com/fadion/Fixerio

Then, all you have to do is something like that:

```
$exchange = new Exchange();
$exchange->base(Currency::USD);
$exchange->symbols(Currency::EUR, Currency::GBP);

$rates = $exchange->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

A good code snippet is to use the [Foreign Exchganges API](https://exchangeratesapi.io/) In order to f the job. A sample code is the following:

```
    function currencyConverter($from, $to, $amount)
    {
        if ($from != $to) {
            $json = getJSONetP('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=' . strtoupper($from));
            return intval($json['rates'][$to] * $amount);
        }
        return $amount;
    }
```

The `getJSONetP` is a fuction used to receive reponses in [`jsonp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) format.

Comment: Please provide detail about your answer.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.